# digital dashboard - running multiple setInterval, permanently

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

I'm currently working on a digital dashboard, where I e.g. display the weather, my calendar, a random cite, some crypto rates, etc.

All these elements are refreshed with ajax. Some (for example the time) are refreshed every second, the weather now is refreshed every 10 minutes, the weather for the upcoming hours every 30 minutes and the weather for the next days every 6 hours. The cite is refreshed every 24 hours and the crypto rates are refreshed every 60 seconds.

My point is: I have about 10 `setInterval`s on my dashboard, most of them doing AJAX requests to my server, with timings between 1000 ms and 86400000 ms. Is there any problem with that or will JavaScript be easily able to handle this? Not worried about my server getting the requests, this will work fine, but is JavaScript able to handle these mutliple `setInterval`s, especially considering that the web page won't be refreshed usually (I mean, not at all, for months, if everything works fine at least)...

Does anybody have experience with this or (if that's an issue) suggest a better way to do it?

EDIT: what I forgot to mention, might be important as well, in case of performance, the dashboard is running on a Raspberry PI 3B+..

Comment: polling your server every second is not ideal, depending on size of response thats 86k requests a day per user. If you want realtime use websockets.. then you only need push data when it comes in rather then polling it.

Comment: Should be fine,,. Even on pi.  But like pointed out, webSockets would be nicer.

Comment: Measure it. Use the `Performance` tab in Chrome. It comes with the ability to record performance over a period of time. It also comes with `Performance monitor` that shows CPU Usage, JS Heap Size, DOM Nodes, etc. But I think the only thing to really worry about is the every second refresh. The rest of timers have much bigger intervals, so it shouldn't be a problem, really. Although I would say it makes more sense to open websockets channel, which keeps the connection alive for as long as the client is connected instead of opening a new connection via HTTP so regularly

Comment: thanks for the comments to all. Then I think I'm on the good side, as the 1 second refresh (forgot to mention) is for the time, which just uses JS's `date` command, so there are no requests to my server on any other page for that.